# Erwin kreyszig functional analysis Page.82 Ex.4

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness

> Show that for an infinite subset $\mathbb{M}$ in the space $\mathbb{S}$ to be compact, it is necessary that there are numbers $\gamma_1, \ \gamma_2,\dots$ such that $\forall x=(\xi_k(x))\in \mathbb{M}$ we have $|\xi_k(x)|\leqq \gamma_k$. (It can be shown that the condition is also sufficient for the compactness of $\mathbb{M}$)

I would be grateful if anyone could explain this exercise and told me how to solve it?

Comment: Many people can. The real question is, what have you done so far?

Comment: @an4s would you like to help me ?

Comment: You can look this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045772/erwin-kreyszigs-introductory-functional-analysis-with-applications-section-2-5