# Erwin Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications, Section 2.5, Problem 4

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Here is the Problem 4 in Section 2.5 in *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwin Kreyszig:

> Show that for an infinite subset $ M $ in the space $ s $ to be compact, it is necessary that there are numbers $ \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \cdots $ such that for all $ x = (\xi_k(x)) \in M $ we have $ \left| \xi_{k}(x) \right| \le \gamma_k $. (It can he shown that the condition is also sufficient for the compactness of $ M $.)

Here the metric space $ s $ is defined as the set of all sequences of real/complex numbers, together the metric $ d(x,y) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^j} \dfrac{|\xi_j - \eta_j|}{1 + |\xi_j - \eta_j|} $ for $ x = (\xi_j), y = (\eta_j) $. One can show that this is a complete metric space.

Actually, the original problem is easy to solve, and my question concerns the commentary in the parentheses: "It can he shown that the condition is also sufficient for the compactness of $ M $". I tried to prove this but got stuck somewhere. Here is what I've done:

> Let $ (x_n) $ be any sequence in $ M $. For any $ \epsilon > 0 $, one can show that there is a subsequence $ (x_{n_k}) $ and an integer $ K $ such that $ \forall k,k' \ge K, d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_{k'}}) < \epsilon $. In fact, let $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \sum\limits_{j=N+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^j} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} $. For any fixed $ j $, the sequence $ (\xi_{j}(x_n))_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is bounded. Thus there is a subsequence $ (x_{n_k}) $ such that $ (\xi_{j}(x_{n_k})) $ converges for $ j = 1, \cdots, N $. Therefore $ \exists K $ such that $ \forall k,k' \ge K, \dfrac{1}{2^{j}} \dfrac{\left| \xi_{j}(x_{n_k}) - \xi_{j}(x_{n_{k'}}) \right|}{1 + \left| \xi_{j}(x_{n_k}) - \xi_{j}(x_{n_{k'}}) \right|} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2N} $ for $ j = 1, \cdots, N $. This ensures that $ \forall k,k' \ge K, d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_{k'}}) < \epsilon $. Set $ \hat{x}_1 = x_{n_K} $.

> Repeat the above process with $ (x_n) $ replaced by $ (z_m) = (x_{n_{K+1}}, x_{n_{K+2}}, \cdots) $ and $ \epsilon $ replaced by $ \epsilon/2 $. One finds a subsequence $ (z_{m_j}) $ and an integer $ J $ such that $ \forall j,j' \ge J, d(z_{m_j}, z_{m_{j'}}) < \epsilon/2 $. Set $ \hat{x}_2 = z_{m_J} $. Obviously $ d(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2) < \epsilon $.

> Continue with the iteration, with the initial $ \epsilon $ chosen as $ 1/2 $, one finds a subsequence $ (\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2, \cdots) $ of $ (x_n) $ satisfying $ d(\hat{x}_{i}, \hat{x}_{i+1}) < 1/2^{i} $. Thus it is easy to show that $ (\hat{x}_i) $ is Cauchy.

In order to show compactness, one has to show that $ (\hat{x}_i) $ also converges in $ M $. Of course, if $ M $ was closed in $ s $, then the completeness of $ s $ would ensure the completeness of $ M $, which completes the proof. However I cannot see any reason for $ M $ being closed with the given condition. I'm wondering if the original text missed this condition or there's any way around this issue?

Comment: I think you are right.  If $$M=\{(t,0,0,0,\ldots): 0<t<1\},$$ then $M$ satisfies the given condition, but is clearly not compact.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good observation!